# Chrome developer tools crashes with specific font usage

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, crash, font-face

I'm using a font called "Lato", which was downloaded from the author site and converted to the proper formats using fontsquirrel.

After including the below CSS, Chrome developer tools crashes when I try to inspect text elements..

Here the font face code I'm using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('../fonts/custom/lato-reg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/custom/lato-reg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/custom/lato-reg-webfont.svg#latoregular') format('svg'),
    url('../fonts/custom/lato-reg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/custom/lato-reg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('../fonts/custom/lato-bol-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/custom/lato-bol-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/custom/lato-bol-webfont.svg#latobold') format('svg'),
    url('../fonts/custom/lato-bol-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/custom/lato-bol-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This happens even If I just use one of these font-face declarations.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This font appears to be on Google Fonts - assuming it is the same one? Give this a try instead of the Font Squirrel conversion: http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lato

Comment: Using Google is causing rendering issues. Anyway the issue was resolved after placing the code in the top of the CSS file..